# Using discord.py, how can I add a role to a user that contains spaces in its name?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have seen that you can add a role using a bot using discord.py. I want to make my code so that you can add roles with multiple words as its name so you don't get errors like 'Role "Chief" not found' when the command was -giverole Chief Executive Officer. I also want to add another parameter in which you ping the user you want to give the role to.

This is for my discord server. I have got a working code that can give a role to you (whoever executes the command) and the role can only be one word: E.g. 'Members'

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
```

Input: `-giverole <mention_user> <role_name>` (must be compatible to give a role that is multiple words)

Output: I can sort out a message that it sends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the `Member` to send the role to just like you use it to get the `Role` itself.  To accept multiple-word roles, use the [keyword-only argument syntax](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).  You can also use role mentions when invoking the command. (e.g. `!giverole @Patrick @Chief Executive Officer`).

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    await client.say(f"Giving the role {role.mention} to {member.mention}")
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I don't want to ping the role is if the amount of members increase. Say of their is 200 moderators and I ping all of them 10 times a day just to give someone the role, then that would be a bit annoying.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get the role from a string, in this case `role_name`

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, *,role_name:str):
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role_name)
  await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
```